# iOS 13 - applicationWillTerminate from UIApplicationDelegate equivalent for UISceneDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios13, uiscenedelegate

I'm using iOS 13 and its new `UISceneDelegate` and I want to execute a function when app is killed.

I used to use the `applicationWillTerminate` function from `UIApplicationDelegate` but I don't see this function in `UISceneDelegate`.

So what is the best way to do it using `UISceneDelegate` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still inside `AppDelegate`

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("applicationWillTerminate")
}
```